# correct permissions for a secrets file using dynamic user in systemd

Tags: systemd

I have a secrets file that I want a systemd service to read. I am using `DynamicUser=True` for this service and `ConfigurationDirectory=foo` and I have placed the secrets file in `/etc/foo/` however if the file is owned by root then the service cannot access it. I can only get things to work if I give 0644 permissions to the file. This seems kind of rubbish, really I want only that service plus root to be able to access the file. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I bet you could use:

```
ExecStartPre=+/usr/bin/install --owner=%u --mode=600 -T /etc/foo/secrets %T/secrets
```

The `+` prefix infont of `/usr/bin/install` ensures that this is run with root permissions (and so it has read-permission on the source file).  Then we copy it to `%T` which is a privately mounted temporary directory and set the owner to `%u` which is the dynamic user name.  The copy may also solve some concurrency issues if you have multiple instances of the service using the same file.

Comment: I tested your suggestion, and I'm finding that `%u` and `%T` refer to `root` and the system `/tmp`, respectively when the command is prefixed with the `+` like you've written (ubuntu 20.04). In fact, according to the [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers) `%u` is `the name of the user running the service manager instance. In case of the system manager this resolves to "root". Note that this setting is not influenced by the User= setting configurable in the [Service] section of the service unit.` I like your idea; I'll post if I find a solution.

Comment: Looks like there is a [`LoadCredential`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#LoadCredential=ID:PATH) key name in [systemd 247](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/16568). Unfortunately I'm running 245. 

Answer (score 0):

As [joshua.r.smith](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/423325/joshua-r-smith) points out, you can use [LoadCredential](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.exec.html#LoadCredential=ID:PATH). It will copy the file from your config to `/run/credentials/example.service/`, set permission 500 and the user `example:root`.

An example will be:

```
[Service]
...
LoadCredential=config.json:/usr/local/etc/example/config.json
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/example --config ${CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY}/config.json
```

You can also use `LoadCredentialEncrypted` if you want the credential file to be encrypted.